VBA, ¿Cómo hago para que los botones CommandButton X y Autoformas se muevan de acuerdo al Scroll del Mouse arriba, abajo y la Barra espa Dercha, Izqda
Tipo de consulta: Macros (BOTONES FLOTANTE)
Primero que todo ya vi videos en youtube, los pocos que hay pero no es exactamente una solución.
Tengo una plantila en excel en donde tengo Autoformas que sirven como botones, osea le asigne macros para que ejecuten una función en especifico y tengo CommandButton Active X, igual con macros asignadas, dicho eso:
Alguno de ustedes ha hecho una macro para que las autoformas o botones no se pierdan de vista, osea que queden visibles, de manera que si bajas con el scroll el boton igual baje y si te mueves a la derecha ya sea a la última columna tambien se vaya hacia la derecha respetando la posición en la que lo dejaste.
Descarto de ante mano la inmovilización de paneles, puesto que si voy hacia la derecha me quedan visibles los botones ubicados en columnas pero se me mueven las filas, de la misma manera si bajo, los botones de las filas se quedan visibles porque esta inmovilizado, pero los que tengo en la izquierda columna se quedan arriba.
Agradecido de ante mano por su ayuda !


¿Dónde esta el código o algoritmo que usas en tu aplicación? Para mover un botón se utiliza el nombre del objeto que es el botón y sus propiedades Left y Top para moverlo por el formulario...
